# Prevent redirection when form is submitted

Tags: html, forms

What I want is to submit a form in the background, so that it doesn't redirect to the form "action." Is there a clean way to do this, without using external libraries like jQuery?

Comment: You are looking for ajax. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If you submit a form, you will redirect.

What you can do, however, is to "serialize" the form, get the URL (I'm assuming GET), and request the server using XmlHttpRequest (Ajax).

There's a question on SO about serializing a form without jQuery: [how to serialize a form without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334519/how-to-serialize-a-form-without-jquery)

Also, this one on how to use XMLHttpRequest: [How to get the response of XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038901/how-to-get-the-response-of-xmlhttprequest)

jQuery kind of makes both tasks easier, though